# TextView is not updating on time

Tags: android, textview

I have following sample code to understand the TextView update

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    int i=0;    
    private ImageButton btnMain;
    private TextView txtText;
    Context mycont=null;

    public void myJob(final String cmd)
    { 
        //txtText.setText(cmd);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                txtText.setText(cmd); //---Does not update the TextView here on Main UI
            }
        });     

        //----------- Long Work(Take around 15 seconds to complete) ----------
        for(i=0;i<=1000000000;i++)
        i++;                        

        for(i=0;i<=1000000000;i++)
        i++;
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------

        //---Update the TextView here once above Long work is executed
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        mycont=this;

        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
        txtText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());


        btnMain = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnJob);          
        btnMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {   
                myJob("Display this msg");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

TextView is not updating on time, its waiting for other procedure to execute.
Please point me in right direction. I want to Update the TextView in the beginning of the myJob() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to update the textview, then run the `Long Work`. In that case do something like this:

```
public void myJob(final String cmd)
{ 
    txtText.setText(cmd);

    txtText.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //----------- Long Work(Take around 15 seconds to complete) ----------
            for(i=0;i<=1000000000;i++)
            i++;                        

            for(i=0;i<=1000000000;i++)
            i++;
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        }
    });
}
```

*Note: In either case, your long work is running on the UI thread.. because you have never created a background task*

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link: [How will UI changes be processed in the onClickListener before starting a new activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717722/how-will-ui-changes-be-processed-in-the-onclicklistener-before-starting-a-new-ac)

"Changes to UI elements are not executed immediately. They're executed the next time the UI loop runs, which is after you release control."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look into [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). They allow you to perform actions before and after doing a timeconsuming job. In your case your `AsyncTask` would look somewhat like this:

```
 private class LongJob extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    TextView textViewToChange;

    public LongJob(TextView text){
        textViewToChange = text;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
    // Executed on main(UI) thread
        textViewToChange.setText("Some random text here");

    }

     protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
          // Your long job here, executed on background thread so 
          // it won't freeze your application.
         return null;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
     // Executed on main(UI) thread
        textViewToChange.setText("Text for after your job completed");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Amulya and Sander.
Both the solutions worked for me.

But as per my need, i will go for the solution by Amulya which is lightweight.

I was already aware of Android AsyncTasks.
But never thought of using in this way.

Thanks to both of you

Comment: Stackoverflow differs from a traditional forum and to thank someone for posting a useful answer you only need to up-vote their post.  Additionally, if an answer solves your problem then you are encouraged to accept it (you are able to change your mind later, say if a better solutions is posted.) This helps future readers of your question to pinpoint the solution that worked for you.  All this info can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/about and http://stackoverflow.com/help , and specifically _What happens after I ask a question?_ in http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts